# How to loop over XML child nodes using groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, assertion, xmlslurper

I have an XML response as below:

```
<ns:Envelope xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <ns:Body>
    <ns:response xmlns:svc="http://...serviceNameSpace" 
                xmlns:ent="http://....entitiesNameSpace">
        <ns:customer>
            <ns:contact>
                <ns:type>firstclass</ns:type>
                <ns:email>kevin@....com</ns:email>
                <ns:details>
                    <ns:name>Kevin</ns:name>
                    <ns:area>Networking</ns:area>
                </ns:details>
                <ns:address>
                    <ns:code>39343</ns:code>
                    <ns:country>US</ns:country>
                </ns:address>
             </ns:contact>
            <ns:contact>
                <ns:type>secondclass</ns:type>
                <ns:email>john@...com</ns:email>
                <ns:details>
                    <ns:name>John</ns:name>
                    <ns:area>Development</ns:area>
                <ns:address>
                    <ns:code>23445</ns:code>
                    <ns:country>US</ns:country>
             </ns:contact>                 
        </ns:customer>
    </ns:response >
</ns:Body>
```

I am trying this to iterate childnodes details and address to validate the response with the request properties. But I could assert email but couldn't go into details (name and area) and address (code and country). Below is the code I am using

```
import groovy.xml.*

def envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
def type = 'secondclass'
def emailAddress= ${properties#emailAddress}

envelope.'**'
.findAll { it.name() == 'contact' }
.findAll { it.type.text().contains(type) }
.each {
        assert emailAddress== it.emailAddress.text()
    }
```

Please help me in iterating the nodes details(name and area) and address (code and country) for assertion

Comment: You mean to say if you receive the same data in the response as that was sent in the request? Then, please add your request as well by editing the post.

Comment: Nope request is not same as response data. That is different, I am setting properties seperately with the values. And I want to assert it by validating the xml data with already set properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it seems that your xml is slightly broken with missing closing tags. I took the liberty of fixing that in the example below.

Conceptually, when you are navigating through the xml with expressions like `xml.Envelope.Body.response` you are navigating through xml nodes. Note the distinction here between xml nodes (i.e. elements) and the actual data or text within the nodes.

The xml nodes returned from XmlSlurper are represented as descendants of the groovy [GPathResult](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) class. These descendants include NodeChild, NodeChildren, NoChildren, and Attribute, all of which can be returned by an `xml.Envelope.Body.Response` type of query depending on how the query and the xml looks. To retrieve the actual text data within a node you need to call `node.text()`.

With the xml fixed and the above in mind, the following code:

```
def str = '''\
<ns:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<ns:Body>
    <ns:response xmlns:svc="http://...serviceNameSpace" xmlns:ent="http://....entitiesNameSpace">
        <ns:customer>
            <ns:contact>
                <ns:type>firstclass</ns:type>
                <ns:email>kevin@....com</ns:email>
                <ns:details>
                    <ns:name>Kevin</ns:name>
                    <ns:area>Networking</ns:area>
                </ns:details>
                <ns:address>
                    <ns:code>39343</ns:code>
                    <ns:country>US</ns:country>
                </ns:address>
             </ns:contact>
            <ns:contact>
                <ns:type>secondclass</ns:type>
                <ns:email>john@...com</ns:email>
                <ns:details>
                    <ns:name>John</ns:name>
                    <ns:area>Development</ns:area>
                </ns:details>
                <ns:address>
                    <ns:code>23445</ns:code>
                    <ns:country>US</ns:country>
                </ns:address>
             </ns:contact>                 
        </ns:customer>
    </ns:response >
</ns:Body>
</ns:Envelope>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper(false, true).parseText(str)

def contactNodes = xml.Body.response.customer.contact

assert contactNodes.first().email               == 'kevin@....com'
assert contactNodes.first().details.name.text() == "Kevin"
assert contactNodes.first().details.area.text() == "Networking"

assert contactNodes.last().email               == 'john@...com'
assert contactNodes.last().details.name.text() == "John"
assert contactNodes.last().details.area.text() == "Development"
```

runs and all the assertions succeed.

The `contactNodes` variable is a [groovy NodeChildren](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChildren.html) object and can for all intents and purposes be treated as a List of nodes (i.e. you can call methods like [`.each {}`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html#each(groovy.lang.Closure)), [`.every {}`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html#every(groovy.lang.Closure)), [`.any {}`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html#any(groovy.lang.Closure)), ... on it).

**edit in response to comment**: To iterate only over contact nodes with specific properties, you can do:

```
xml.Body.response.customer.contact.findAll { contactNode ->
    contactNode.type.text() == 'firstclass' 
}.each { firstClassContactNode -> 
    assert firstClassContactNode.email.text() == "kevin@....com"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please tell me if I want to iterate the xml when the type is firstclass . I want to iterate those xml data and assert it

Comment: Thanks Matias, I could already assert email address for that type can you please help me in asserting details and address child nodes for that type

Comment: I tried with this.     .each { details -> assert details.name.text()== "Kevin"}          Getting groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren@1e46e7a (to.String()=="") message

Comment: Thank you Matias. I got it worked. Appreciate you help.

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end. If you feel that the answer solved your problem satisfactorily, feel free to mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get the 'contact' node by filter type = "secondclass".
Secondly, based on the results of step 1, make a test on each item.

Your groovy script will be changed like this:

```
    import groovy.xml.*
    
    def envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml);
    def type = 'secondclass';
    def emailAddress= ${properties#emailAddress};
    
    envelope.Body.response.customer.contact
         .findAll {contactNode -> contactNode.type.text() == type}
         .each{ currentNode -> assert emailAddress== currentNode.emailAddress.text()};
```